# Автоматическая десериализация объектов в JSON(C#)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, json.net

Доброго времени суток.

В ASP.NET Core есть удобный функционал, который позволяет на серваке при отправке запроса формировать параметры с помощью объектов, а, например, на сервере приемнике есть метод контроллера, который принимает при передаче !объект!.

Тобишь происходит автоматическая сериализация и десериализация объектов в JSON'e. Десериализация происходит в зависимости от структуры JSON

Вопрос: где отыскать подобный механизм работы? В Newtonsoft.JSON нужно явно указывать, во что преобразовать. В стандартной библиотеке C# тоже самое.

**Update 1.**

Тут не указывается тип, в который я хочу преобразовать строку, потому что я не знаю, что ко мне вообще пришло. Но все объекты описаны. Тобишь приходит JSON и в зависимости от структуры преобразуется в соответствующий ему тип.

Пример: то, что может быть(предложение @Андрей)

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
```

Еще вариант(что нашел я)

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
```

Что я хочу(является примером того, чего я хотел бы видеть):

```
dynamic m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);//Это пример и он может быть не корректным, но отображает суть. Тут не указывается тип, в который я хочу преобразовать строку, потому что я не знаю, что ко мне вообще пришло.

var b = m as Robot;
```

**Update 2.**

Как работает это в ASP.NET Core
Допустим есть Controller c методом.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            }
        }
```

Маппинг к этому методу произойдет, только если на Клиенте будет сформирован JSON такой же структуры, как и класс RegisterViewModel.

**Update 3.**

Я хочу, чтобы при получения JSON он преобразовывался в объект ему соответствующий. Нужно мне это, потому что JSON много и по сути все получаемые JSON - объекты. Внутренняя структура программа работает не с JObject, а с объектами. Задача тупая - по JSON воссоздать объект.

Comment: В Newtonsoft.JSON есть возможность десериализовать в `dynamic`, вроде. Это подойдет вам?

Comment: @Андрей Андрей, уточнил вопрос. Почти то что надо, но мне нужно, чтобы создавался не объект по JSON, а JSON в зависимости от структуры приводился к соответствующему ему типу.

Comment: Это как? подробнее опишите.

Comment: @Андрей в Update 1 добавил. Добавлю еще как это работает в ASP.NET Core

Comment: "а JSON в зависимости от структуры приводился к соответствующему ему типу" - здорово. "Я еще не волшебник ..."

Comment: @Igor очень полезно, но сие волшебство уже реализовано. Вопрос лишь есть ли подобное еще где-то, ибо в ASP.NET Core мне это понравилось.

Comment: Если вопрос в том, чтобы приводить JSON к нужному типу, указанному в JOSN, то JSON.NET позволяет это делать, если включить информацию о нужном типе при сериализации. Однако, не понятно, зачем такое может понадобится при разработке API

Comment: @Arantler Вам не нравится, что в "Newtonsoft.JSON нужно явно указывать, во что преобразовать", и Вы тут же приводите пример, где явно указано, во что преобразовывать (`RegisterViewModel`).

Comment: @Arantler Конкретизируйте пожалуйста вопрос, так как не ясно что вы хотите сделать, зачем и в чем проблема

Comment: @Igor В Update 1 находится 3 примера. Первые 2 - это то, что есть и что мне не подходит, а третий пример, что я бы хотел бы видеть. Дык дело в том, что таким именем методов несколько, а входные данные(объекты) разные. Тем самым в зависимости от того, какие данные передаются, происходит автоматический маппинг по структуре и вызывается нужный метод.

Comment: Предлагаю создать класс контейнер для ваших объектов в котором будет содержаться ваш объект и какой-нибудь идентификатор типа отталкиваясь от которого вы будете выбирать объект в который необходимо преобразовать строку.

Comment: @V.Dmitriy это первое, что пришло мне на ум. Но зачем воротить велосипед, когда возможно уже есть решение. Если решения нет, то сделаю именно так.

Comment: @tym32167 а можно пример или ссылку про приведение к нужному типу, используя отметку в JSON? Не нашел такого.

Comment: @Arantler К сожалению, о таких решениях я не слышал.

Comment: @Arantler добавил ответом

Comment: @V.Dmitriy возможно вам будет интересен ответ на вопрос. По смысле то, что я и вы подумали с самого начала. Правда, все же, при передаче из фронта в вэб в ASP.NET Core, мы нигде не указывает тип. Главное, чтобы совпадение со структурой было 100%

Comment: @Arantler да, это интересно. Спасибо что обратили моё внимание. :)

Comment: @V.Dmitriy вам спасибо за проявленный интерес к вопросу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коммент не вмещается, сделаю ответом. 
Просили пример, когда JSON.NET выбирает тип десериализуемого объекта на основе данных в JSON

Сделаем класс

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

Сериализуем

```
var ob1 = new Foo() { Id = 10 };
var serialized1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ob1, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
}); 
Console.WriteLine(serialized1);
```

Получим JSON, где будет прописан тип объекта

```
{
  "$type": "UserQuery+Foo, query_uypuvq", // я делал в LINQPad, потому такой странный тип
  "Id": 10
}
```

Ну, и считаем его

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized1, new JsonSerializerSettings() 
{ 
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects 
});
Console.WriteLine(deserialized.GetType().FullName);
```

На выходе получим

```
UserQuery+Foo
```

Но, имхо, в АПИ такому не место.

ps. [Нашел доку с примером](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm)

Comment: Круто, то что я хотел(очень близко). Но почему не это в АПИ не место? Я использую для общения DTO.

Comment: спасибо большое. Это не то, как работает в ASP.NET, но возможно даже лучше. Больше контроля над происходящим

Comment: @Arantler я считаю, что этому не место в апи, так как оно 1) Усложняет логику АПИ, 2) Завязывает ваш АПИ на используемые типы - вы их ни переместить, не переименовать не сможете. ИМХО, для разных типов сущностей должны быть разные методы в АПИ

Comment: я не спорю(точнее спорю в хорошем смысле), просто пытаюсь докопаться до сути вашего сообщения 1. А каким образом оно усложняет логику?Если инкапсулировать преобразования, то наверх настройка не попадает(тобишт уже то же самое).
2. Хм, а именно это и нужно. Только я завязываю не на типы, а на параметры, которые описываю с помощью объектов(тобишь обычно просто параметры), а я делаю то же самое, только удобнее и нагляднее.  И...Почему не могу переименовать? Сервер и клиент используют одну и ту же библиотеку DTO(для отправки получения). Там же есть классы Сериализации и Десерилизации.

Comment: 1. Сколько тестов у вас будет на метод? Подумайте над этим. Что лучше, 10 простых методов по 1 тесту или 1 сложный метод и 10 тестов? Тот, кто будет читать и поддерживать ваш код после вас, вспомнит ли он о вас? 2. Если вы используете публичное АПИ, то клиента у вас нет, он у потребителей. Если это внутреннее АПИ для каких-нить микросервисов, то при переименовании типов вам придется релизить все, что эти типы использует, так как сразу ломается обратная совместимость.

Comment: То есть я не говорю, что оно работать не будет. Оно запросто взлетит. Но просто с таким решением вы сами себе на ровном месте добавляете головной боли при поддержке, деплое, совместимости версий и проч.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66193/discussion-between-arantler-and-tym32167).

Comment: В чат, к сожалению, не могу. Рабочий файервол не пустит